# String.equalsIgnoreCase returns true only for first switch case

Tags: java, string

In my code given below where I am parsing characters from a text file, the analyse(String word) function is returning the right value only for the first time its called. After that, it returns false for every other String even when the String is equal to the compared String (or at least seems like it). Why?

```
void parsing() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    String inAddress = "Text To Be Parsed.txt";
    String outAddress = "Copied File.txt";
    in = new FileInputStream(inAddress);
    out = new FileOutputStream(outAddress);
    int c;
    String word = "";
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        if (c != 13) {
            if (c == '.') {
                System.out.println(word);
                System.out.println(analyse(word));
                word = "";
            } else {
                word += (char) c;
            }
        }
    }
String analyse(String word) throws IOException {

    switch (word.toLowerCase()) {
    case "hello":
        return "English";
    case "konnichiwa":
        return "Japanese";
    case "anneyong":
        return "Korean";
    case "guten tag":
        return "German";
    case "bonjour":
        return "French";
    case "bonjorno":
        return "Italian";
    case "como esta":
        return "Spanish";
    default:
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

The following is my text file:

> Hello.
>
> Konnichiwa.
>
> Anneyong.
>
> Bonjour.
>
> Guten tag.
>
> Bonjorno.
>
> Como esta.

The following is the output of this code:

```
Hello
English

Konnichiwa
Error

Anneyong
Error

Bonjour
Error

Guten tag
Error

Bonjorno
Error

Como esta
Error
```

Comment: Your `case` statement is missing breaks after each condition.  Hence, the logic is falling through to the error case for most words.

Comment: why don't you use `readLine` ?

Comment: A break added after a return is not reachable anyway. Also Eclipse throws an error when I add a break.

Comment: Could you show me a snippet as to how to use readLine? I initially wanted to, but I guess I don't know how to use it properly in this context.

Comment: I think the problem is that the CRLF is being added to your `word` - see the gaps in your output

Comment: No need to use `break;` statement here as It returns value when it finds a match!

Comment: Aren't you adding '\n' to the begining of the each next word? You are checking if the char is '\r' (13) but not '\n' (line feed, 10). That's why you are getting empty line in the output and each following word is not equal.

Comment: Can you upload the Exact Text file without any modification in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your words are holding more info than you need (new line chars)..
[image]

that is the reason why your analyse method never match the words you are reading, you need to get rid off the new line char before calling the **analyse** method..

Comment: Ahh, yes I missed a bit of my code there. I've edited my code. It was supposed to 

`in = new FileInputStream(inAddress); `

which I was going to use later.

Comment: Yep. This was the problem. Fixed it by replacing the line feed with an empty character. Thanks.

Comment: @ShreyasYakhob there you are!!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be use a BufferedReader and readLine

```
BufferedReader in
        = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inAddress));

String c;
while ((c = in.readLine()) != null) {

        String word = c.replace (".", "");        
        System.out.println(word);
        System.out.println(analyse(word));
}
```

Comment: But readLine cannot be used for an object of the class FileInputStream. :|

Comment: The while statement is throwing an error in Eclipse: Incompatible operand types String and int

Comment: my goodness - such bad mistakes from me today.  see my new `while`

Comment: Sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 0):

As `ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ` mentioned, The problem here is that you are considering only `\r` characters to not to be taken while you are ignoring `\n` characters So here when the fuction call is made, It has argument as `\n+Word` while It should be `Word` only.

So you can modify the `if` condition of `while` loop and add another condition that the `character` should not be `\n`.

You can modify the if condition as : `if (c != 13 && c != 10) \\10 is Ascii value for \n`

Code:

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    if (c != 13 && c!=10) {
        if (c == '.') {
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println(analyse(word));
            word = "";
        } else {
            word += (char) c;
        }
    }
}
```

This will solve your problem. Another and better approach is to use `trim()` method which eleminates `unwanted white spaces` from the word. So you can use this function in `switch` argument to eliminate the `white spaces` from the word.

It can be done by changing `switch` condition as `switch (word.toLowerCase().trim())`.